# cleanup endpoint should be allow through curl command

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have disabled cleanup endpoint in my application.yml file and marked false also to enableByDefault property. I should not access it through curl command.
but still through curl command, i am able to access cleanup endpoint. is anything missing here?

```
        http://localhost:9001/app/cleanup/1000

        management:
          security:
            enabled: false
          context-path: /app
          endpoints:
            web:
              base-path: /app
              exposure:
                include: health, loggers, cleanup
            enabled-by-default: false
          endpoint:
            cleanup:
              enabled: false




        @Component
        @Slf4j
        @Endpoint(id = "cleanup", enableByDefault = false)
        @RequiredArgsConstructor
        public class CleanuEndpoint {


            @RequestMapping(produces = {
                    ActuatorMediaType.V1_JSON,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
            @ResponseBody
            @ReadOperation
            public Object updateId(@PathVariable Long Id) {
                log.info("updateId() - END= cleanUp={}, id={}",cleanUp, id);
                return delegate.invoke();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked. 
I removed @PathVariable and used @Selector. 
now cleanup endpoint is enabled and disabled based on "management.web.exposure.include" values.

```
        URL:- http://localhost:9001/app/cleanup/1000

            @Component
            @Slf4j
            @Endpoint(id = "cleanup")
            @RequiredArgsConstructor
            public class CleanuEndpoint {
                @ResponseBody
                @ReadOperation
                public Object updateId(@Selector Long Id) {
                    log.info("updateId() - END= cleanUp={}, id={}",cleanUp, id);
                    return delegate.invoke();
                }
```

Thanks to all.